# How can I walk automatically in games that don't support it?

Tags: keyboard

Some games, such as *Dear Esther* or *The Vanishing of Ethan Carter*, might not provide an **auto-run** key binding and I have to hold down <kbd>W</kbd> key for the whole duration of my walking/running.

Is there a way to force the auto-run feature in games that don't natively support it?

Comment: What about the old stone-on-the-keyboard technique?

Comment: There should be a better way to tag this question, since it's not about a specific game; but I can't find an appropriate generic tag. :-(

Comment: @Bob2Chiv updated to `keyboard` tag

Answer (score 2):

The `W` key can be held down by an [AutoHotkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoHotkey) script instead of using one's own finger, e.g.: https://github.com/Aprillion/banished_utils/blob/master/toggle_w.ahk

```
; press back mouse button to hold down W, press again to release W
~XButton1::
  if (w) {
    SendInput {w up}
    w := 0
  } else {
    SendInput {w down}
    w := 1
  }
Return

; release W when S or W are pressed manually (i.e. stop auto running)
; no need for SendInput {w up} when W itself is pressed,
; but we need to set w := 0 after either S or W are pressed (=> no Return after ~s::)
~s::
  SendInput {w up}
~w::
  w := 0
Return
```

Comment: bit of a weird way to do it, but +1 for using AHK :), why not use w instead of XButton1?

Comment: @Aequitas I still want to be able to move only a little, e.g. in fights (though not in the games I listed huh)